# Can't login into mysql on minikube

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, phpmyadmin, minikube

I'm trying to make phpmyadmin and mysql run together on minikube but I cannot login into phpmyadmin or mysql. It always gives me this error:

```
bash-4.2# mysql -u root -p     
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The deployments/pods are running:

```
sens@sens-k8s:~$ k get deployments
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello-minikube          1/1     1            1           9h
phpmyadmin-deployment   1/1     1            1           27m

sens-k8s:~$ k get pods -o wide
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS       AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
hello-minikube-77b6f68484-h5w7r          1/1     Running   2 (143m ago)   9h    10.244.0.35   minikube   <none>           <none>
mysql-pod                                1/1     Running   0              27m   10.244.0.57   minikube   <none>           <none>
phpmyadmin-deployment-5c65bc9df8-thdwd   1/1     Running   0              28m   10.244.0.56   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

Here's the .yml files I've used for it.

secret.yml (supposed to be super simple, e.g. 1234 for test but doesn't work anyways).

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  root-password: MTIzNA==
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-deployment
  labels:
    app: phpmyadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: phpmyadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: phpmyadmin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: phpmyadmin
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: PMA_HOST
              value: mysql-service
            - name: PMA_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: root-password
```

ingress.yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-http-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: phpmyadmin.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: phpmyadmin
            port:
              name: http
```

service.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: phpmyadmin-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: phpmyadmin
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

```
sens@sens-k8s:~$ kd pod mysql-pod
Name:             mysql-pod
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Wed, 29 Mar 2023 05:47:16 +0300
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.57
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.0.57
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   docker://f4b17e73e134c6337513989202537c4fa73b3acba92e2eefaf5be801bdfaf8b2
    Image:          mysql:5.7
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mysql@sha256:1780318bdabc0edd36907bf91b47632eb912e8ea91258eca3590f8aca6f54836
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 29 Mar 2023 05:47:17 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  mypassword
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from mysql-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-t82sp (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  mysql-data:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-t82sp:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Well, you've shown the `phpadmin` side but not the `mysql-pod` side in order to know what mysql should expect was its root password. This story gets even more complex if that mysql-pod mounted an already initialized database directory, in which case it would ignore the env-var and thus you'd need to reset the root password if you don't know it

Comment: @mdaniel I just added what it returns after  k describe on the mysql-pod. Could also include the logs if needed.

Comment: Logs are always great, but for your mysql command, did you use `mysql -u root -p1234` or `mysql -u root -pmypassword`?

Comment: @mdaniel I fixed it. Found the k8s docs and it worked. It was the PVC bugging up for some reason but it worked using the docs.

Used this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/

Comment: The secret was another issue as well, I replaced it with just 

- name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password